# ASP.NET how to write code for mail sender?

Tags: asp.net

I have search many sites. But I can't understatnd what they said. Refer in internet they told to create CDO files.

Please help me to send mail in my Project. I have 3 textboxes:

1. Tomail
2. Heading
3. Content of the message
4. Send Button

Comment: try http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-email-using-Gmail-SMTP-Mail-Server-in-ASPNet.aspx..explain in brief..First try this..if you get any problem in between post code that you tried

Comment: I don't know how do you search https://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=how%20to%20send%20mail%20in%20asp.net&oq=how%20to%20send%20mail%20in%20asp.net&rlz=1C1PRFC_enGB670GB670&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.10924j0j7

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code to sent mail.

```
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("me@mydomain.com");
            mail.To.Add("u@urdomain.com,rkrishtring@gmail.com");
            mail.Subject = "Report";
            mail.Body = "This is a Stack overflow using report";
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment(filename);
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            SmtpServer.Port = 25;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```